# My code does not stop running and forces me to force quit the Excel file?

Tags: excel

I have modified a piece of code I found in one of the answers on here, but when i run my modified code it performs as desired/expected. After print value, it then continues running and forces me to use task manage to quit the program.

I have adapted the cpde that @JeffB put and it works great, it finds the cell i want and prints it.

However, after doing so it continues to run and doesnt stop. To the point where I have to use task manager to quit, any ideas?

Ive included the modified code below

Microsoft is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action"  is the error that appears, and acts as if its in a loop as everytime i close the msgbox is appears again.

**I am just running the macro by pressing the play button when on the module screen.**

````
Public Sub version_control()
    Dim serverFileName As String 'obtain url for sharepoint filename, insert below
    Dim valuesAreDifferent As Boolean 'so we can do housekeeping below
    Dim x As New Excel.Application 'make a new session for the sharepoint version
    Dim w As Workbook 'grab-handle for the sharepoint file
    Sheets("VC").Calculate
    valuesAreDifferent = False 'implicit, being explicit
    serverFileName = "http://whatever-domain.com/MySharepointWorkbook.xlsx"
    x.Visible = False 'so it doesn't flash up when checking
    Set w = x.Workbooks.Open(serverFileName) 'open the sharepoint version
    If Sheets("VC").Range("A1").Value <> w.Sheets("VC").Range("A1").Value Then _
        valuesAreDifferent = True
    'housekeeping in case we don't quit
    w.Close
    x.Quit
    Set w = Nothing
    Set x = Nothing
    If valuesAreDifferent Then
        MsgBox "Please download the latest version from the Sharepoint"
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```
````

Comment: There shouldn't be anything in here that is recurring. How is this code called?

Comment: I was just running as a normal macro? Now im trying to make it into a function but taking some work

Comment: It says when ran "Microsoft is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action" and then keeps saying this when closed like its in a loop

Comment: Any ideas? @Plutian

Comment: It's most likely the file you're communicating with not closing properly. I can't say I have much experience with communications outside of excel, but [maybe this can help](https://appuals.com/fix-microsoft-excel-is-waiting-for-another-application-to-complete-an-ole-action/) to fix it or remove the error message.

Comment: This was correct, i forgot to think about the Do you want to save a file pop up when an excel file is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of searching, i think i have reached the answer.

When the file is closed, Im assuming it comes up with the do you want to save etc. So adding this code in seems to let it run as desired.

```
ActivityWS.Close SaveChanges:=False
```